# Passing optional parameters to Strapi query without creating model definition?

Tags: geolocation, filtering, optional-parameters, strapi, bounding-box

I want to pass an additional parameter `geoDistance` to my Strapi endpoint. This parameter should be used by the controller to run a calculation first and afterwards query those records which contain certain longitude / lattitude values.

Example: lets assume that my collection type `realestate` contains the fields `cityName`, `longitude` and `latitude`, so my request / path would look something like this:

```
GET /realestate?cityName=Berlin&geoDistance=5
```

If I do this, I get an error (if the field doesn't appear on my model definition):

```js
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Your filters contain a field 'geodistance' that doesn't appear on your model definition nor it's relations"
}
```

But I don't want it to be on my model definition, because it should only be used temporarily before running the actual (bounding box) query, e.g. something like this:

```js
if (ctx.query.geodistance) {
  const geodistance = ctx.query.geodistance
  const { longitude, latitude } = getCityDegrees(ctx.query.cityName)
  // use geodistance in combination with lon, lat, etc...
}
```

So the question is if there is a way to pass params without a model definition? Because the param itself should not appear inside the database.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by passing the value not via a url query, but instead via a dynamic route parameter. Therefore I have a defined a new routes object like this:

```js
{
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/realestate/distance/:distance",
  "handler": "Realestate.find",
  "config": {
    "policies": []
}
```

And then used it like this `const distance = ctx.params.distance` ...

If there is another solution to this, I am happy to hear about it.

Comment: General question: When it comes to the actual distance calculation, are you using a raw query, and if so, are the Strapi standard model functions still working?